# Unix Search (grep)

Tags: unix, grep

I am new to unix and i know the command to search for a certain words in the file is through Grep.

With my command

```
'grep STAR file.txt | grep PTEXT | grep SNUM  > results.txt'
```

The grep command will return the following content which includes all the other details tag along with the same line.

```
STAR=20140201 14:01:05|PTEXT=sample1|SUBM=retapp@S01GRETCD1|SBID=retapp|SNUM=232356|....
STAR=20140201 14:02:05|PTEXT=sample2|SUBM=retapp@S01GRETCD1|SBID=retapp|SNUM=556677|...
STAR=20140201 14:03:05|SUBM=retapp@S01GRETCD1|SBID=retapp|SNUM=768764|....
STAR=20140201 14:03:05|PTEXT=sample3|SUBM=retapp@S01GRETCD1|SBID=retapp|SNUM=768764|....
```

Is there a way to get the results as follow:

```
STAR=20140201 14:01:05|PTEXT=sample1|SNUM=232356|....
STAR=20140201 14:02:05|PTEXT=sample2|SNUM=556677|...
STAR=20140201 14:03:05|PTEXT=sample3|SNUM=768764|....
```

Results expected : ROWS that includes all the THREE Variables without any other redundant data

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `awk` and select the columns you need. Set the Input and Output Field Separator to `|` as your data is delimited by that. Once the line is split, just pick the columns you need. `$1` will contain column1, `$2` will contain column2 and so on ...

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{print $1,$2,$5}' file.txt
```

Use `perl` if you are not sure which columns contain your data.

```
perl -F'\|' -lane 'print join "|", grep { /STAR|PTEXT|SNUM/ } @F' file.txt
```

Inside `grep` we are using simple regex to match any of the three specified string. You can alter them as you deem fit.

Update based on new requirement:

```
perl -F'\|' -lane 'print join "|", grep { /STAR|PTEXT|SNUM/ } @F if /SNUM/ && /PTEXT/ && /STAR/' file.txt
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. But i have an issue, the results i want may not be on a fixed column

Comment: @user1004413 Added a `perl` variant which does not depend on column numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much. However the grep { /STAR|PTEXT|SNUM/ } will also grep rows that have either values for the variables. Is there a way to grep rows that has all 3 variables? Like an AND Rule?

Comment: @user1004413 You're welcome and thank you for accepting it. I have added a new one-liner to meet that requirement. Please leave a comment if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to delete `SUBM=`, `SBID=` fields. If yes, then you may try the below perl command.

```
$ perl -pe  's/\|SUBM=[^|]*|\|SBID=[^|]*//g' file
STAR=20140201 14:01:05|PTEXT=sample1|SNUM=232356|....
STAR=20140201 14:02:05|PTEXT=sample2|SNUM=556677|...
STAR=20140201 14:03:05|PTEXT=sample3|SNUM=768764|....
```

Comment: While this may work for the sample data, I am inclined to believe that those `....` refer to many more columns which are present on the same line.

Comment: yep. I think he don't want to delete many more columns which are on the same line.